# Erasing line features based on intersecting polygons using GeoPandas?

Tags: python, clip, geopandas, shapely, erase

I have two interesecting `geopandas.GeoDataFrame` datasets, one containing line features (`lines_gdf`) and one containing polygons (`polygons_gdf`):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import geopandas as gpd
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, LineString

# Create sample polygon and line data
polygons_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[Polygon(zip([150, 151, 151, 150], 
                                                      [30, 30, 31, 31]))])
lines_gdf = gpd.GeoDataFrame(geometry=[LineString(zip([148, 150, 152], 
                                                      [28, 30, 32]))])

# Plot example data
polygons_gdf.plot()
lines_gdf.plot(ax=plt.gca(), edgecolor='red')
```

[image: Example of intersecting line and polygon datasets]

**Desired output**

I want to use my polygons dataset to remove or erase any part of my lines dataset it intersects with (essentially a [GIS "erase" operation](http://wiki.gis.com/wiki/index.php/Erase)), and return only the non-overlapping parts of my lines (i.e. black lines below):

[image]

Using the `geopandas.clip` tool I've been able to do the exact opposite of what I need to do: clip the data to keep (not remove) the intersecting portion of my lines:

```
# Clip lines to keep only area within `polygons_gdf`
clipped_gdf = gpd.clip(lines_gdf, polygons_gdf)

# Plot clipped lines over the top of input layers
polygons_gdf.plot(alpha=0.1)
lines_gdf.plot(ax=plt.gca(), edgecolor='red', alpha=0.1)
clipped_gdf.plot(ax=plt.gca(), edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

**My question:** How do I use `geopandas` to remove/erase part of a line dataset that intersects with a polygon dataset?

My `geopandas` version is v0.6.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A colleague helped me out with this one:

1. **Upgrade `geopandas` to version 0.7.0 or above**. Prior to version 0.7.0, this function supported polygon operations only. Version 0.7.0 introduced the [following change](https://github.com/geopandas/geopandas/releases/tag/v0.7.0):

> The `geopandas.overlay` function now works for all geometry types,
>   including points and linestrings in addition to polygons

2. Use the `geopandas.overlay` function with `how='difference'`:

```
erased_gdf = gpd.overlay(lines_gdf, polygons_gdf, how='difference')
```

This now gives me the result I required:

```
# Plot output over the top of input layers
polygons_gdf.plot(alpha=0.1)
lines_gdf.plot(ax=plt.gca(), edgecolor='red', alpha=0.1)
erased_gdf.plot(ax=plt.gca(), edgecolor='black')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used geopandas much, but when I did, I needed a similar operation. Try looking at the [set operations](https://geopandas.org/set_operations.html). The one you're after is "symmetric difference".